# How to split files in a spa built with Vue.js into public and private parts?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, webpack, vuejs3

I want to split an SPA app I'm building with Vue.js and Ionic into a public part (with login, request password and little else) and the rest...

I've discovered it is possible to create a Multi-Page Application with webpack and using HtmlWebpackPlugin but it is not clear for me how to use it...

Any examples you know of?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate more about what is public and what is private? And what is the goal of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the first part of the implementation...
You need a javascript entry file for each part plus a separate router file...
Then in the vue.config.js you can add...

```
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    publicSide: {
      entry: 'src/main.ts',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      title: 'Public Page'
    },
    privateSide: {
      entry: 'src/private.ts',
      template: 'private/index.html',
      filename: 'private.html',
      title: 'Private Page'
    }
  }
}
```

I still have to figure out how to generate 2 output folders instead of one...